# Set GLSurfaceView as Live Wallpaper in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, live-wallpaper, shiva3d

I'm `Java/Android/Shiva3D/Unity3D` developer.

But I never have created android live wallpapers.. so I need some help..

I want to create 3D Live Wallpapers with Shiva 3D. After exporting project as android project from Shiva3D.. I'm getting project,

which is containing 3 classes. One is
    **GLSurface View**.. and the second class is implementing it relative layout. now I want to use it in live wallpaper. How I can do it? I'm trying to add **GLSurfaceView** to Relative layout.. but I can't set relative layout as live wallpaper..

So can someone help me to set **GLSurfaceView** as live wallpaper?

Comment: I have some OpenGL based live wallpapers on GitHub, e.g. https://github.com/harism/android_wallpaper_yinyang . You can take a look there how I tackled ``GLSurfaceView`` into live wallpaper.

Comment: thanks.. I'll try.. but do you know some sort ways? I have everything. just need to set GLSurfaceView as live wallpaper..

Comment: Fundamentally, what I'm doing, is overriding ``getSurface()`` method in ``GLSurfaceView`` and return ``Engine.getSurfaceHolder()`` instead. This will attach ``GLSurfaceView`` into surface assigned for wallpaper.

Comment: hmmm... can you do it if I send you project? please...

Comment: @harism, you're code demonstrates, in a simple way, how to achieve this. Other tutorials and libraries do this more complex than necessary. Thanks!